# Simple ordering in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with the following data

```
    id   | name    |   passed    | rank    | Class
    1      abc           y           1        1
    2      xyz           y           1        2
    3      lmn           n           54       1
    4      opq           n           54       2
    5      rst           y           2        1
    6      uvw           y           2        2
```

What sql query can give me the following result:

```
    id   | name    |   passed    | rank    | Class
    1      abc           y           1        1
    2      rst           y           2        1
    4      def           y           55       1
    3      lmn           n           54       1
    5      xyz           y           1        2
    6      uvw           y           2        2
    7      opq           n           54       2
```

1. Group by class first all students with class = 1 , then 2 and so on.
2. the passsed == n should always come by the end and if there are 2 students with passed == n they should be ordered rank wise.
3. rest of the students with passed == y should be orders rank wise.

Tried:

```
select id, name, passed, rank, class
from students
ORDER BY passed DESC, rank
```

This gives :

```
    id   | name    |   passed    | rank    | Class
    1      abc           y           1        1
    4      xyz           y           1        2
    2      rst           y           2        1
    5      uvw           y           2        2
    3      def           y           55       1
    6      opq           n           54       2
    3      lmn           n           54       1
```

So I get passed==n at bottom and rest ordered as per rank.I think the only thing remaining is group by class.

Comment: Please show your attempts.

Comment: Kindly provide the sql statement which you tried out. You are not asking doubt. You are giving requirement to SO members.

Comment: It makes no sense that an id would suddenly become associated with some other name. But I imagine `ORDER BY class, FIELD(passed,'y','n'), rank` is what you're after.

Comment: Please ignore the ids.

Comment: It's getting worse.

Comment: Try `ORDER BY class, passed DESC, rank`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just add the order or class first?

```
select id, 
        name, 
        passed, 
        rank, 
        class
from students
ORDER BY `Class`, 
        passed DESC, 
        rank
```